# Geocoder gem delay causing the page to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I don't know how to get my code nice and clean anymore ... and I still end up with a nil location object in some cases, which I am trying to avoid ... and I cannot repro the error at the office. Until then I am getting those error by email where the app cannot find latitude or country_code on nil object (the location object)

So what should I do to make sure that location get to be "Paris, France" is the IP or the address don't work out for Geocoder?

```
def find_current_location_from_ip(ip)
    unless Geocoder.search(ip).nil? || Geocoder.search(ip)[0].nil?
      @location = Geocoder.search(ip)[0].country_code == "RD" ? 
          Geocoder.search("Paris, France")[0] : Geocoder.search(ip)[0]
    else
      @location = Geocoder.search("Paris, France")[0]
    end
    @location
end

def find_current_location_from_address(address)
    Geocoder.search(address).blank? ? 
        Geocoder.search("Paris, France")[0] : Geocoder.search(address)[0]
end
```

Any tips would be fantastic. Also it looks like that if I refresh the page the location gets suddently right and country_code on nil object error disappears ... ??

I am little confused about I can address the latter just now.

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 0):

Occasionaly Geocoder can return an error without raising an exception. This is caused when the API you are using (google, yahoo, etc..) returns an API error. The default API is google. They have a daily request limit of 2500, which if you are not using an API key that you signed up for, uses the IP address of the server to determine if the limit was exceeded. That's the most likely cause of your problem.

You need to check that there is actually data in the `@location` variable before you access it.

I believe you can check like so:

`puts @location[:country_code] unless @location.empty?`